# I want to store a message which is in <p> tag in selenium web-driver with ruby bindings

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I want to store `"The id you entered does not exist in our database. Please note, ids are case and space sensitive."` in a variable.

```
<p class="message fail"> The id you entered does not exist in our database. Please note, ids are case and space sensitive. </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
your_variable = driver.find_element(:class, 'message fail').text
```

The `.text` method will give you the text of an element.